# Can't turn testcase into failed state

Tags: robotframework, allure

I am trying to make Robot framework and Allure to work together.
And I didn't manage to mark a test case as failed.
StepFailureEvent and TestCaseFailureEvent turn test case into broken state.
Please advise me what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `TestCaseFailureEvent` contains `AssertionError` test will be marked as failed, marked as broken otherwise

```
protected Status getStatus() {
    return throwable instanceof AssertionError ? Status.FAILED : Status.BROKEN;
}
```

PS. You can override this logic using custom `TestCaseStatusChangeEvent`